# Making a user pick first item in a ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I have items in a array list that i need to check for matches.

The matches in the array list are in order as they should be called by the user.

for example.. red, green,orange. are all in an array list in order as the user should match then.

The problem is i cant figure out how to make the user call the items in order as they appear.

Right now here is how i am trying to do it to no avail..

```
//Here i try to check to see the order being clicked matches 1 item less than the array list size.
if(this.getUserData() == Manager.getInstance().currentList.get(size-1)){

                //Here we produce the ingredient since it matches an item in the list.
                produceSquare();
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

                //if the order matches an item in the array list, we remove that item.
            Manager.getInstance().currentList.remove(size-1);
```

This isnt working. Right now, if i have 2 items that need to be matched, the second item has to be clicked before the first one..i want it to be the other way around. meaning the first item in the list must be called before the last item.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are asking to `get(size-1)`, shouldn't it be `get(0)`?

Comment: I don't think your question is very clear-  you have an arrayList of some items.  You want to force the user to do something to them in order (I have no idea what).  And by users, do you mean users of the phone or of your code?  If the first, you should just disable all the other items.  If the second, you shouldn't be giving your calling code access to an ArrayList if you don't want random access.

Comment: Users meaning the player of the game. The thing is the items are in the array list each time a match is made for the user to match. The user has to click a item and then the code above is supposed to check it against the first item in the list or whatever the next item is. Right now instead of the user having to click the items in oder they appear the user has to click the second item first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your broken code makes the user click in *reverse* order. You need to change

```
currentList.get(size-1)

currentList.remove(size-1)
```

to

```
currentList.get(0)

currentList.remove(0)
```

to make user click in order.

Comment: Yep! I figured this out about 10 minutes before seeing your answer.